# I want to link my website to the aws amazon sign up page directly

Tags: url

It displays the following in the url,how can I reduce it to the domain name of this page alone.I need to give the following link in my html code as "href" hence i need just the domain name.

```
         https://www.amazon.com/ap/signin?openid.assoc_handle=aws&openid.return_to=https%3A%2F%2Fportal.aws.amazon.com%2Fgp%2Faws%2Fdeveloper%2Fregistration%2Findex.html&openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&action=&disableCorpSignUp=&clientContext=&marketPlaceId=&poolName=&authCookies=&pageId=aws.ssop&siteState=awscustomer&accountStatusPolicy=P1&sso=&openid.pape.preferred_auth_policies=MultifactorPhysical&openid.pape.max_auth_age=3600&openid.ns.pape=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fextensions%2Fpape%2F1.0&server=%2Fap%2Fsignin%3Fie%3DUTF8&accountPoolAlias=&forceMobileApp=0&forceMobileLayout=0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
<a href="https://portal.aws.amazon.com/gp/aws/developer/registration/index.html">AWS login</a>
```

Comment: can u explain how this is done??I'm a newbie .It would certainly help me understand it better @aidan

Comment: I went to the main page https://aws.amazon.com and copied the URL form the 'Sign Up' button ;)